# Using Same Column multiple time in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, db2, where-clause

I am looking for a way to write a query that returns results where columns can be used multiple times in a WHERE statement. Can't find the best way to do this.

```
SELECT
  EMPLOYEE, CATEGORY, STATUS
FROM
  EMPLOYMENT
WHERE 
  (CATEGORY = 1 AND STATUS LIKE '%A%') AND (CATEGORY = 2 AND STATUS = 'B')
```

Comment: I think you just want to change AND to OR.

Comment: So you want to find all employments on category 1 with and 'A' in their status, plus all employments on category 2 with status 'B'?

Comment: Sorry for the wording, so of everyone that is in category 1 and status LIKE '%A%', which of them are also in category 2 and with a status that is 'B'.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I tagged IBM DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want employees that have these conditions.  If so, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE
FROM EMPLOYMENT
WHERE (CATEGORY = 1 AND STATUS LIKE '%A%') OR
      (CATEGORY = 2 AND STATUS = 'B')
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CATEGORY) = 2;  -- matches both
```

Comment: Received a RC -514

Comment: And what is a "RC-514"?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n514.html

Comment: I found the issue that caused the -514 error. It was a user error on my part... but looks like the query you suggested works perfectly. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want 'Or' here:

```
    SELECT EMPLOYEE, CATEGORY, STATUS 
      FROM EMPLOYMENT 
      WHERE CATEGORY = 1 AND STATUS LIKE '%A%' 
and employee in (select EMPLOYEE from EMPLOYMENT where 
           CATEGORY = 2 AND STATUS = 'B')
```

Comment: I am more so looking for everyone that is in category 1 and status LIKE '%A%', which of them are also in category 2 and with a status that is 'B'. So trying to see who fits the criteria for both scenarios without running an additional query. Is that possible?

Comment: I tried it, still not getting a result. Receiving a RC -514.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are already using the using the column name multiple times (EX. `CATEGORY = 1` and `CATEGORY = 2`).

But the question is not clear enough, to give you an actual answer for the question.

Inner join:

```
SELECT e1.EMPLOYEE, e1.STATUS
FROM EMPLOYMENT as e1
Inner join EMPLOYMENT as e2 on
  e2.EMPLOYEE = e1.EMPLOYEE and e2.STATUS = ‘B’ and e2.CATEGORY = 2
WHERE (e1.CATEGORY = 1 AND e1.STATUS LIKE '%A%')
```

This will show all employment record for the employees with CATEGORY = 1 and all the statusses containing an A, for which the same employee also has STATUS B in CATEGORY 2

It should return the same result as the query of @Daniel

Comment: I am looking for everyone that is in category 1 and status LIKE '%A%', but I am also want to know which of them are also in category 2 and with a status that is 'B'. So trying to see who fits the criteria for both scenarios without running an additional query. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, @R. Hoek, Looks like Gordon's suggestion gave me my expected results, but I will try your suggestion as well. Thank you for the help.